# Linker error undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Tags: c++

I have the following linker error and I suspect this has to do with linker that is being used but I don't seem to know where this problem is from.

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

I am working in Dev C++ please on windows Vista Professional machine

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char * pointarrty = "234";
    int a = 0;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you making a console application or a GUI application?

Comment: It can also happen if you don't have a `main` at all (yes, I've done that before).

Comment: It would be easier to tell what was the problems if we could see the code.

Comment: It sounds me like you did'nt include <commctrl.h>...

Comment: @unkulunkulu, In `@x`, `x` is the total size of the parameters.

Comment: @chris, right, my comment is invalid, `WinMain` does use `__stdcall`, it was some recognition mistake on my side :D

Comment: It is a console application. And I am building it in Dev C++

Comment: @user272671, then you probably selected a wrong type of application when you created your project, because it looks for `WinMain`, which is a sign of general `Win32` application. You could start a new project and look at every option carefully keeping in mind that you want _console_ application, not general `Win32`. Or you could try looking in the project settings for this.

Comment: Just a side note: Use `const char *` (or an array) instead of `char *` for string literals. String literals have the type `const char[]`, so casting them to a pointer to non-const data is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx) :

If you are using Unicode and MFC, you will get an unresolved external on _WinMain@16 if you don't create an entrypoint to wWinMainCRTStartup; use the /ENTRY. See Unicode Programming Summary.

To set the entry point, refer, the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx) article

Comment: Was having the same issue as the OP and this solved it. I used the alternative 'mainCRTStartup' but got everything rolling. Thanks